# I can't use onGenerateRoute, because there is always an error

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't use onGenerateRoute because there is always an error. I watched different tutorials but I can't find the problem. GenerateRoute behind the "Route>dynamic>" is always underlined red.
This is my "route_generator.dart" file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rave/src/app.dart';

class RouteGenerator{
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings){

  }
}
```

and this is my "app.dart" file, the RouteGenerator behind "onGenerateRoute:" is also underlined red:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:rave/src/Screens/init.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xff1f1f1f),
        canvasColor: const Color(0xff1f1f1f),
      ),
      home: InitScreen(),
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what does the error say if you hover the mouse? is it perhaps `the body might complete normally, causing null to be returned`?

Comment: Yes it says: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.  I added an return statement at the end but it didn't changed anything

Comment: did the return statement return a route or nothing at all?

Comment: Nevermind I was just too stupid :) I've wrote the return statement in the wrong line but now it works

Comment: glad it got resolved!